# Facebook tests users with user to user requests

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I asked this question last week but only got 8 views.

A part of the application I'm working on requires creating a ton of user-to-user requests and validating they all get processed correctly in the application. This requires countless hours of QA work and could be automated with a simple script like

```
users_api = Koala::Facebook::TestUsers.new(config)

users = test_users.create_network(10, true, "email,user_likes,publish_actions")

users.permutations(2) do |u1, u2|
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(u1['access_token'])

  requests_types.each do |req|
    graph # .user_to_user_request(u2, req) Oh noes I can't do this part
  end
end
```

Everything I've seen points to the fact that it's impossible to create user-to-user requests in a script, even for test users. Is there any other (automated) way to do this?

#### Edit

What I'm trying to find is a way to create user-to-user requests. The validation would still be manual by the QA team. The problem we're facing is that they need to create 90 requests and make sure they didn't skip a single one, then validate the data.

Comment: is some kind of automated browser-driven testing out of the question? for example something like http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ ?

Comment: Yes, Selenium or Capybara are out of the question

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this is tricky one. You probably have two solutions, depending on what you need.

First one is to manually provide access tokens for tests. That would require creating several fictional users or gathering access tokens from friends via [Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). This is of course very inconvenient, but probably needed for second idea so I'm mentioning it. The question is how much users will you need to test? In most situations 3-4 users should be enough to provide test case.

Second idea will require actually running tests suite once using first idea and recording results using gems like [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) or [fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb). This will allow you to remember what API response will serve and using it in later tests without need to regenerate tokens. This should also speed up your tests significantly as will avoid waiting for each request from FB API.

Comment: The first part of your idea can be solved with the test users API. It provides functionality to create users on-demand, and create a friendship network.

The second part of your answer is the opposite of what I want. I need to actually _create_ the user-to-user requests on FB, after which the QA team will validate them in the application. I'll edit my question to make this clearer